# Can't use render(controller) in SonataAdminBundle template

Tags: symfony, sonata

I create custom controller(extending Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController) and action.

When render this action `{{render(controller('MainBundle:SonataAdmin/Order:searchCertificate'))}}`


I get Symfony error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `MainBundle\Controller\SonataAdmin\OrderController` and the current route").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer in official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html#bringing-it-all-together):

> If you want to render a custom controller action in a template by
>   using the render function in twig you need to add _sonata_admin as an
>   attribute. For example; {{
>   render(controller('AppBundle:XxxxCRUD:comment', {'_sonata_admin':
>   'sonata.admin.xxxx' })) }}. This has to be done because the moment the
>   rendering should happen the routing, which usually sets the value of
>   this parameter, is not involved at all, and then you will get an error
>   "There is no _sonata_admin defined for the controller
>   AppBundleControllerXxxxCRUDController and the current route ' '."

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this Problem by setting the _sonata_admin in the comming request:

with normal Controller:

```
$request->request->set('_sonata_admin','admin.template');
```